# Spring Data JPA: Example from Spring in Action don't run

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I try to start an example from Spring in action 5. STS shows me the error:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-06-24 10:47:06.472
>   ERROR 6300 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

This's example may receive there: [GitHub - Spring in action: Spring Data JPA](https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples/tree/master/ch03/tacos-jpa)

Can you help me? If need yet codes from example, I can copy here.

Comment: Place a no-args public constructor for https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples/blob/master/ch03/tacos-jpa/src/main/java/tacos/Ingredient.java

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what I must do? My Inrdedient.java is the same as the GitHub. Should I add something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example does not run with Java > 8.

You have to use Java 8 to run it as it is.

Spring Boot 2.0.x does not support Java 11.

You should upgrade the example to 2.1.6

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain to me what Should I change that it's run with Java > 8? If I change <java.version>1.8</java.version> on <java.version>11</java.version> it will be enough?

Answer (score 0):

I try to re-produce your error, I catch the same

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor
>   for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister

I read comment [Spring Data JPA: Example from Spring in Action don't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732077/spring-data-jpa-example-from-spring-in-action-dont-run#comment100023407_56732077)

Changing

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
```

to

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PUBLIC, force=true)
```

does not resolve problem. Keep it like original.

Solution:

(1) I am using JDK 12. Add dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

(2) Program argumnet

```
--illegal-access=ignore
```

Result: In console log, applicaton run sucesss

> Hibernate: insert into ingredient (name, type, id) values (?, ?, ?)

Comment: Just for your interest: Spring Boot 2.0.x does not support Java 11. That's the cause of the problem